# Unable to download product export csv in Magento

Tags: magento2, product, export

While downloading product.csv file in MAGENTO getting below error:

The webpage at https://example.in/bradadmin/admin/export_file/download/filename/catalog_product_20230517_143650.csv/key/1c1eb7cdbcf882d3db091bd5d83d4d7ced5515a543fa255f0c1bc4e520dcbe42/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

[image]

---

Hosting is in AWS.

Please HELP!!!